# Drupal website Videos (MP4 files) not working on any browsers but google-chrome

Tags: drupal, mp4

I have a page filled with a list of videos. The videos are stored in the server as MP4 file. The videos are not working on any web browser but google-chrome. I don't understand why. Thank you in advance for replying.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of reasons for this:

1. Does the other browsers have the necessary plugins to play these videos?
2. Is your drupal video setup configured properly? what version of drupal are you using BTW? if drupal 7 i can point you to a tutorial on setting up videos.